# Bulk importing to SQL Server from a remote data file using UNC paths

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openrowset, bulk-import

As mentioned on the MSDN for [bulk import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#bulk-importing-to-sql-server-from-a-remote-data-file), I tried to use UNC path for importing data but it fails.

```
SELECT
    '\\FS1-CBR.strange.ibm.au\{fu-spec}\work\Proj1 Vis-NIR_all\New South Wales\file1.asd',
    * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'\\FS1-CBR.strange.ibm.au\{fu-spec}\work\Proj1 Vis-NIR_all\New South Wales\file1.asd', SINGLE_BLOB) AS FileData
```

It fails with error:

> Cannot bulk load because the file
> "\FS1-CBR.strange.ibm.au{fu-spec}\work\Proj1 Vis-NIR_all\New
> South Wales\file1.asd" could not be opened. Operating system error
> code 5(Access is denied.).

I guess it is failing due to the substring ***{fu-spec}*** in the UNC path. I can access the file through file explorer as well as programmatically as I have the permissions to this location.

How to import the file in this case using ***OPENROWSET BULK*** in SQL Server?

Comment: Did you try to give access to *everyone* for *read/write* permission? If it works, just find out under which user SQL server access and give permission for that user.

Comment: Are you sure that the SQL Server service account has access to that path?

Comment: @Larnu i will verify that

Comment: As mentioned in the answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/208199/134112 , I remote desktoped directly into the server machine running SQL server and then opened SSMS on the server to run the bulk import and it runs fine. So my permissions were not being delegated forward if I opened SSMS on a workstation and use it to connect remotely to the SQL server to run the bulk import. Thanks for the permissions hint though.

Comment: The error message seems to be missing some backslashes, `"\FS1-CBR.strange.ibm.au{fu-spec}\...` Are you sure the code you're executing is the same as posted?

Comment: `OPENROWSET` will use SQL Server's account, not the account logged in on SSMS. When you remote in, was the path *exactly* the same, with the braces in it and the same share server?